# Laradock lost data (mysql)

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-ec2, laradock

I deployed two laravel projects on Laradock but sometime ago (about 2-3 days). Now, my databases on mysql are lost!
My server is AWS EC2, and I didn't shutdown or stopped laradock. Is it a bug or did I missing anything?
Update: My Mysql Dockerfile:

```
ARG MYSQL_VERSION=latest

FROM mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}


LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"


#####################################

# Set Timezone

#####################################


ARG TZ=UTC

ENV TZ ${TZ}

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > 
/etc/timezone && chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/



COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf



CMD ["mysqld"]



EXPOSE 3306
```

My SQL on docker-compose.yml

#### MySQL

```
mysql:
  build:
    context: ./mysql
    args:
      - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
    - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
  volumes:
    - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    - ${MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  ports:
    - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
  networks:
    - backend
```

Comment: show your dockerfile. Did you attached volumes to your containers?

Comment: @Manmohan_singh I shown my dockerfile. I used default volumes of laradock like the describe above!

Comment: Thank @Manmohan_singh , I fixed by changed the volumns of mysql to my own folder. The default one is ./laradock/data/mysql